# entity and attribute in e-r model

Tags: attributes, entity

Simple question:

I have e-r model. I have entity Car. Car can be either BMW or Opel. If it is BMW then it must have color. If it is a Opel then it must have attribute - amount of passangers.

How can it be displayed in e-r model? I mean IF clase.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In an ER model this is normally represented as a sub-type.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Sub-types can be exclusive or non-exclusive, depending on whether more than one of the sub-types should apply simultaneously. For example, a Bank Account entity might have sub-types for Current Account or Savings Account. These would be exclusive sub-types since a bank account cannot be both. Depending on the type of the account, one of the sub-types is used to "extend" the main entity. On the other hand an entity named Sportsman could have sub-types Golfer and Footballer. The Sportsman entity would contain common information such as name, and the sub-types would contain only the additional attributes applicable to the sport (e.g. Golf Handicap). Records only exist in the sub-type entities when the main entity is of the applicable type. These would be non-exclusive sub-types since it is quite possible that someone plays both golf and football.

In IDEF1X notation it is represented like this

[image: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IDEF1X_SubSuper.png?]